# Simple example SignalR -1.0.0-alpha2 in ASP.NET MVC 4 VS2012 not working

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, signalr

---

**UPDATE4**: (**SOLVED**)

- made new project;
- imported sources;
- updated SignalR to latest version (through NuGet Package Manager Console);
- made corresponding changes (according to official doc: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-server).

In the end, everything worked like a charm. Thanks SignalR team!

---

good job with this SignalR, can't wait to try it!

I found this tutorial - SignalR - 5 Minute Demo (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tEBaDo_sFfA)

BUT, I have some problems:
- i installed VS2012Ultimate, after creating a sample ASP.NET MVC4 Internet App, right click on References -> Manage NuGet Packages, search SignalR.... doesn't appear like in the video, none of those: SignalR, SignalR.Js, SignalR.Server... :(
Does anyone knows why?

**UPDATE1**:
I installed SignalR (http://nuget.org/packages/microsoft.aspnet.signalr) and after that, i installed that asp.net fall update (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35493).

BUT i get the error from below regarding function "`writeMessage`" from `ChatHub.cs`.

```
"Error1'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubConnectionContext' does not contain a definition for 'writeMessage'
and no extension method 'writeMessage' accepting a first argument of type
'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubConnectionContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
assembly reference? ..\MvcApplication1\Hubs\ChatHub.cs"
```

After "resolving" this error using `Clients.All.` or `Clients.Others.` and start hub just after chat initialization and using `chat.writeMessage`, i get two errors when loading in GoogleChrome Console:

- in **Index.cshtml**:

  ```
  "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'writeMessage' of undefined"
  ```
- in **localhost:3420/signalr/hubs**:

  ```
  "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'createProxy'"
  ```

  - on this **line**:

    ```
    // Create and store the hub proxy
        hub._.proxy = hubConnection.createProxy(hub._.hubName);
    ```

After "resolving" this error using `Clients.All.` or `Clients.Others.` and start hub just at the end, and using `chat.client.writeMessage` (i installed Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client), i get two errors when loading in GoogleChrome Console:

- in **Index.cshtml**:

  ```
  "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined"
  ```

Can anyone help me, please?! :(

Thanks in advance!!

**File** `ChatHub.cs`:

```
namespace MvcApplication1.Hubs
{
    //[Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubName("chathub")]
    [Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubName("chatHub")]
    public class ChatHub : Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.Hub
    {
        public void BroadcastMessage(string message)
        { 
            //rebroadcast the message to all the connected clients
            Clients.writeMessage(message);//ERROR on compile

        //I tried both of the followings, give no error, BUT when i press Submit doesn't appear messages anywhere
            //Clients.All.writeMessage(message);
            //Clients.Others.writeMessage(message);
        }
    }
}
```

**File** `Index.cshtml`:

```
@section scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.0.0-alpha2.js"></script>

@*not working, GET localhost:3420/SignalR 500 (Internal Server Error)*@
    @*<script type="text/javascript" src="SignalR"></script>*@

@*  with any of these declarations i don't get 500 error any more, but still not working *@
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
    @*<script type="text/javascript" src="../signalr/hubs"></script>*@    

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
        //i tried these, but in vain..
            //var connection = new Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Connection("localhost:3420/");
            //$.connection.hub.url = 'localhost:3420/signalr/';

            var chat = $.connection.chatHub;

            $.connection.hub.start();

        //Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'writeMessage' of undefined 
            //chat.writeMessage = function (msg)

        //Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined 
            chat.client.writeMessage = function (msg) {
            {
                $("#messages").append("<li>" + msg + "</li>");
            }

            $("#buttonSubmit").click(function ()
            {
                //chat.broadcastMessage($("#txtInput").val());
                chat.server.broadcastMessage($("#txtInput").val());
            });

            $.connection.hub.start();//just one error at client
        });
    </script>
}
<h5>Chat with SignalR</h5>       
<fieldset>
    <legend>SignalR Demo</legend>
    <label for="txtInput">Chat Message</label>
    <input id="txtInput" type="text" />
    <button id="buttonSubmit">Submit</button>            
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Messages</legend>
        <ul id="messages"></ul>
    </fieldset>
</fieldset>
```

**UPDATE2**:

After **Tim B James**'advices, I:

- created new ASP.NET MVC 4 project;
- installed SignalR via NuGet with suggested commands;
- tried the source code example with Hubs from https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/QuickStart-Hubs but NOT working!

Mentions:

<del>- put the code from function `Main`, into my `HomeController.cs` -> function: `public ActionResult Index()`;</del>

<del>- changed this line:</del>

<del>var hubConnection = new HubConnection("localhost/mysite");</del>

<del>with this one:</del>

<del>var hubConnection = new HubConnection("localhost:14079");</del>

<del>BUT, my  page doesn't load ("Waiting for localhost...")</del>

<del>- if i don't put the code from Main into controller's function,</del>

i get this **error**:

```
    "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'chat' of undefined "
on this line: 

    var chat = $.connection.chat;
```

**UPDATE3**:

UPDATE2 with <del>**strikethrough**</del> lines

**UPDATE4**: (**SOLVED**)

Indications at the beginning.

Comment: You can't put the code from `main` into a controller. That is not how it works. That is code for a console application, and not an MVC controller. Have you read over the documentation? How to create a `persistentconnection`, JavaScript Client, and .Net Client?

Comment: Please, whoever down-voted this question, i ask to justify his/her action!! Thanks.

Comment: @TimBJames 

I thought that might not be good, so that's why I tried both. But when removed code from cotroller, I still get the error `Can not read property 'chat' of undefined"`

Comment: Maybe you're missing to add the routes mapping on Global.asax ...

  protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Register the default hubs route: ~/signalr/hubs
            RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
        }

Answer (score 2):

There are some undocumented nuances with the latest version, in fact I was working through them today.

First off you will not need the Code from Main, in the link you referenced.  That is for using Signalr inside of a WPF app or Windows 8 app.

The first issue that may or may not be an issue, is the use of HubNameAttribute, it may or may not be needed.
Without HubName the name of your hub should resolve to $.connection.chatHub

The next part that you have already handled is the new namespaces on each hub.

```
chatHub.client - These are client defined methods, that the server may invoke.
chatHub.server - These are server defined methods, that the client may invoke.
chatHub.state - This is the state that gets sent to and from the server.
```

Now the uncaught error is something in the JavaScript not getting output correctly, most likely the hubs definition, as the hub variable is whats null.  You need to verify under the covers that the hubs are coming back properly.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

This should return a properly formatted jQuery ready block, that defines all the hubs and server methods for those hubs.  Using a tool like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) will help with this.

I would also start using Chrome or Firefox w/Firebug, both have their advantages and disadvantages, but both will give you a network monitor and debugging facilities.  Being able to catch unhandled exceptions has been a life saver trying to debug all things JavaScript.

Hope this helps you on your quest to solve your outstanding issues.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Regarding code from controller, I removed it (**UPDATE3**), but still get error. I can't verify at the moment "~/signalr/hubs" (not at the working PC) but i remember trying yesterday, and it was an entire page with JavaScript, and in the end there were the definitions of the hubs. Also tried with/without HubName.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the YouTube video is now out of date in relation to the version of SignalR which is now available.

Secondly, I would just delete the project that you are using and start again. This time, install the SignalR Alpha release via NuGet package manager.

**Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR -pre**

**Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.client -pre**

Once you have done this, go and read over the documentation/examples at the SignalR website found here

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki

If you follow some of the basics, then you should be sorted.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried what you proposed, but the example with Hubs didn't work either. Please see my **UPDATE2**.